# setprecision on stream is printing more digits on centos

Tags: c++, g++

I am generating a report of percentages and in order to reduce the size of reports, I want only 3 digits after decimal to be appeared in reports.

I am using C++ fstream for printing the report and code is like this

```
   ofstream outFile;
   outFile.open("TEST.csv");
   if(!outFile.is_open())
   {
            exit(1);
   }
   outFile << std::setprecision(3);
```

Shouldn't the above code restrict the number of digits after decimal point to max 3 ?
I am seeing sometime 4th digit is also getting printed after decimal point like 9.67741966 is appearing as 9.6774.

Can somebody please explain me the above behaviour.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  You don't actually show the code that's printing incorrectly so it does seem likely that there's some other code later on that's calling `std::setprecision` and then failing to restore the old value.